# Prematurely exiting a Loop and Merge block in Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, loops, merge, logic, qualtrics

I'm currently working on a Qualtrics survey in which respondents have to solve a long list of anagrams, and then answer some demographic questions.

To make the anagram part easier, I've used a Loop and Merge block: the first field is the anagram to be solved, the second field is the solution of the anagram, and the survey can therefore check the answer of the respondent against the solution for each anagram.

As it is, the survey is working perfectly: however, I'd like to allow respondents to prematurely exit the loop by typing "EXIT" in the response field, and to redirect them to the next question block (the demographic questions).

This is typically something that is achieved using "Skip" logic: however, skipping to the end of the block does not do the trick (the loop restarts). I managed to redirect them to the end of the survey, but not to the demographic question block.

Is there a way to use javascript to jump to the demographic block or exit the loop and merge block prematurely? Am I missing a Qualtrics option that would do the trick?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this is still relevant to you: I needed the same functionality and this is how I solved it: First, I define a helper variable, call it `EndLoop`, which I initialize to 0. Then I set up a function to change the value of EndLoop to 1 after people hit a button, additionally I add a display logic to the question in the loop showing them only if EndLoop is still 0 and hiding the questions as soon as EndLoop is 1.

This is a step-by-step instruction and the javascript and html code.

The bold stuff is what you need to do, the bulletpoints a more detailed instruction how to do it.

**1. Before your loop-and-merge [define an embedded data field](http://www.qualtrics.com/university/researchsuite/advanced-building/survey-flow/embedded-data/) called `EndLoop` and initialize it as 0.**

- Go to the Survey Flow Panel
- Add a new element > select embedded data field
- Name the field 'EndLoop'
- Set its value t0 the number 0 by click on the link "set value now"
- Make sure you move it before the merge-and-loop block

**2. For each item in the loop [set a display logic](http://www.qualtrics.com/university/researchsuite/basic-building/question-options/display-logic/) to show them conditional on 'EndLoop' = 0**

- Go to the options menu of each question in the loop
- Select "add display logic"
- Select "Embedded Data" from the first dropdown menu
- A new type field opens > as name type `EndLoop` + select "is equal to" + type 0 as value

**3. Insert a customized button into the page where people should be able to opt-out.** The button runs a user-defined function called setEndLoop() onclick.

- Click on the question where the button should appear
- On the top-right of the question text select "html view"
- The code I used is:

  ```
  <input id="css-class-mybutton" onclick="setEndLoop()" value=" done " type="button">
  ```
- If you want to change the button text, change the " done " in `value = " done "`

**4. Define the function setEndLoop() using custom javascript to change the value of EndLoop to 1 and emulate a next button click**

- Go to the options menu of each question in the loop
- Select "add JavaScript"

The code I used is:

```
    /* Get the EndLoop variable */
    var EndLoop = "${e://Field/EndLoop}";

    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function(){

        /* hide previous and next button */
        $('NextButton') && $('NextButton').hide();
        $('PreviousButton') && $('PreviousButton').hide();

        /* Function: on click on user-defined button -> change the field EndLoop */
        var that = this;

        setEndLoop = function(){
            Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('EndLoop', 1);
            that.clickNextButton();
        };
    });
```

The button will not have the default style, thus, define a custom css to style your button to look like the buttons of your theme. The class name for the button I used here is `id="css-class-mybutton"`, use `.css-class-mybutton{ ... }` in the css.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a bit late, but I had a similar issue and wanted to post an alternative solution. I used the loop and merge function, but I didn't want to have participants click on a button to exit the loop, instead I wanted to use a multiple choice question to exit the loop. This question was, "would you like to ask more questions?", with responses yes and no. If the participant selected "Yes" they would keep going through the loop and if they selected "No" they would exit the loop and go on to the next block of questions.

My first two steps are the same as those above.

1.Set up an Embedded data field named EndLoop and set the value to 1.
     - in the survey flow panel select add an element. Then type in the name EndLoop. 
     - Then select set value now and set the value to 1.
     - make sure that this is before your loop and merge block in the survey flow.

2. For each question in the loop and merge block use display logic to ensure that they only display when the embedded data element EndLoop is 1.
3. Now for the question "would you like to ask more questions?" add the following code in the add javascript area.

   - the javascript area can be found by clicking the advanced options button under the question number on the lefthand side of the screen. Select 'Add javascript...'

     - There will be some code already present...it should look like this:

   Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
   {

   /*Place Your Javascript Below This Line*/

   });

   - Basically I used event tracking to update the embedded data field EndLoop to the numerical value associated with the answer choice when the answer choice was selected. In this case the answer "Yes" had a value of 1 because it was the first option and "No" had a value of 2 because it was the second option. When "No" was selected, the embedded data field EndLoop was set to a value of 2. This then meant that none of the questions would display since they have display logic to ensure they only display when the EndLoop field is 1.

My entire code looks like this:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function ()
{
    this.questionclick = function(event,element)
    {
        console.log(event, element);
        if (element.type == 'radio')
        {
            var choiceNum = element.id;
            if (choiceNum == 2)
            {
           Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("EndLoop", choiceNum);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I used the second solution. Here's a minor correction for the script:
I wrote `element.id.split('~')[2]` instead of `element.id`, and it worked!

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function ()
{
    this.questionclick = function(event,element)
    {
        console.log(event,element);
        if (element.type == 'radio')
    {
        var choiceNum = element.id.split('~')[2];
        if (choiceNum == 2)
        {
       Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("EndLoop", choiceNum);
        }
    }
}
});
```