# Qualtrics: Evenly present field elements of a loop across participants

Tags: javascript, loops, merge, logic, qualtrics

I'm currently working on a Qualtrics survey in which respondents have to rate pictures on a couple of characteristics.

Given that it's a lot of pictures (300), participants shouldn't have to rate all of them but can choose to exit once they've had enough. I used [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25766238/prematurely-exiting-a-loop-and-merge-block-in-qualtrics) to allow participants to exit the loop and subsequently the study.

Problem: I need a certain number of ratings for each picture, say 30.

Is it possible to put a limit on how many times a picture is presented in a loop, after which this particular picture is left out for subsequent participants?
Alternatively, it might also suffice to have an "present evenly" option for the loop elements, but I can't find it.

Is there a way to use JavaScript to achieve this? Or is there an option in Qualtrics that could do the trick?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'present evenly' on loop elements by adding a MC question prior to the loop with all your loop elements as choices.  Use Advanced Randomization with 'evenly present' on the question and hide the question with JS. Then base your loop off the displayed choices in the hidden question.

If you want to set a limit on each loop element you can create a quota for each element and create a hidden MC question like above. Add choice display logic to the MC question based on whether the choices' quotas have been met.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not sure this is what I'm looking for. Given that I want to add all elements to the loop for every participant and not restrict the number of options shows beforehand, all it does is randomise the loop order which the loop itself already does. The same is true for the quota solution since for this to work I would have to restrict the number of shown loop elements beforehand. However, I want participants to decide themselves if they spend 5min or 30min on the study. Should my understanding be wrong, I'd be glad if you could clarify. Thanks.

Comment: If you just want to leave certain images out use the quotas approach I gave.  Evenly present won't do anything is you are showing everyone all loop rows (except the ones you hide based on quotas).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I spent the weekend adding the display logic and the quota for each of the 300 pictures. Unfortunately, this appears to disable the "premature exit" function of the loop. I'll try to find a solution where both works, thanks anyway :)